# Add method to decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

In [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) documentation about `lru_cache` I can see that there's the possibility to call a function on a decorator with the dot notation, for instance I can call:

```
lru_cache_decorated_func.cache_info()
```

What I'm trying to achieve is make my own decorator with my custom function to call that works and is called like `cache_info()`.

So how I can add  such a function to a decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator is nothing more (or less) than a callable returning a callable[0] aka

```py
@foo
def bar():
   ...
```

is exactly the same as:

```py
def bar():
    ...
bar = foo(bar)
```

There are various options to "smartify" decorators, what lru_cache does is pretty simple:

- it wraps the decorated function in a `wrapper` function
- it then sets to attributes on that `wrapper` function
- and it returns the wrapper (swapping the original function for the wrapper)

```py
import functools

def foo(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.thing = 'yay'
    return wrapper

@foo
def bar(): ...

print(bar.thing)
```

will print `yay`.

[0] or even a not-callable, as is the case for `@property` or `@cached_property`.